# very slow php script

Tags: php, performance

When I run the code it is ridiculously slow even if I comment out the second half where I fopen the same file. I have changed the length of stream_get_line. File is 64MB, 73500 lines, 159 columns. Any help to optimize would be much appreciated.

```
<?php

   include "configure.php";
   $row = 1;
   if(($handle = fopen("ACC_half.txt", "r")) !== false)
   {
      global $arraySamples;
      global $arrayTrans;
      global $num;
      global $lines;
      while (!feof($handle))
      {    
         $data = stream_get_line($handle, 1000000, "\n");
         $num = count($data);
         $lines = count(file("ACC_half.txt")); 
         //Get all the names of the samples into array
         if($row == 1)
         {
            for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
            {
               //echo $data[$i];
               $arraySamples[]=$data[$i];
            }
            //Get all the names of the first row(headers) into array for use 
         } 
         else
         { 
            $arrayTrans[]=$data[0];
         }
         $row++; 
      }
   }
   fclose($handle);
   $row = 1;
   $transInc=1;
   if(($handle1 = fopen("ACC_half.txt", "r")) !== false)
   {
      while (($data2 = stream_get_line($handle,1000000,"\n\r")) !== false)
      {
         if(($row == 2) || ($row==1))
         {
            $row++;continue;
         }
         $jnum=count($data2);
         for($j=1;$j<$jnum;$j+=2)
         {
            $g=$j+1;
            $h=$j+2;
            $import = mysql_query("INSERT into acc (form,sample,raw,scale) 
                  VALUES ('$arrayTrans[$transInc]', '$arraySamples[$g]', '$data2[$j]', '$data2[$g]')") 
               or die (mysql_error());  
         }
         $transInc++;
      }
   }
   fclose($handle1);

?>
```

Comment: Output your file read results to an array, and then do an combined insert on the items with the array rather than reading the stream and inserting inside the buffer. There are numerous ways to improve this code, but i would start there.

Comment: What is this doing _inside_ the while loop: `$lines = count(file("ACC_half.txt"));` ? You re-read the file again and again and again! For nothing, since `$lines` is not even used!

Comment: You guys are the greatest. Both tips were very helpful! Thanks!!

Comment: Don't use `mysql_`, its deprecated. Use prepared statements in `myslqi` or `PDO` too, if you're doing a lot of inserts where only the values change, prepared statements will also be a lot faster.

Comment: The whole script is deprecated PHP3 style. `globals`, `mysql_`, ... This won't work either: `VALUES ('$arrayTrans[$transInc]'`... it must be `VALUES ('" . $arrayTrans[$transInc] . "'`

Comment: @DanFromGermany wordpress still uses globals.., so I think its ok to use it in procedural style.

Comment: @Xatenev the wordpress coding style is the WORST ever... they just put it in so wordpress can be run on legacy servers, and because wordpress is originally a fork of b2/cafelog, which was written in ~ 2001? That time, PHP 4.1.0 was the most up to date version of PHP.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Your right, I just wanted to mention that it is probably ok to use it for small scripts when you are a newcomer and don't wanna use OOP PHP. PHP is actually horrible code without OOP anyways. globals and goto are just the tip of the iceberg

Comment: @Xatenev agree with you, peace

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one of the main problems is that you open the same big file twice. You should open this file once not twice